# ASP.net Dynamic Data website Authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, dynamic-data

I have created an ASP.NET Dynamic Data Website using VS 2012.
Now, I need to add authentication/access control to this site.
By default this project type does not come with any Login page,.. to control access to the application.

Could you please suggest a quick and clean way of controlling access?
I do not at this point of time need table level security.
Just letting authorized users to access this application is sufficient.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I'd use Windows Authentication if you are on an Active Directory network.  You can find numerous tutorials online.

Comment: Thanks a lot Garrison! I was able to implement Windows Authentication